# Why can‘t I use wildcards in the "if" in the conditional statement？

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Why does this code display `no` and `no1`?

```
bit[2:0] a;
a=3'b001;
if(a==3'b0??) $display("ok");
else          $display("no");

case(a)
  3'b0?? : $display("ok1");
  default: $display("no1");
endcase
```

I am using VCS. I don't know why the printed result is not expected.

Answer (score 3):

In (System)Verilog `?` is an exact synonym for `z`. It is NOT a wildcard. However, it can be used as a wildcard in some situations, but not your situations. Here are those situations:

```
if(a ==? 3'b0??) $display("ok");
//   ^^^
else           $display("no");

casez(a)
//  ^
  3'b0??: $display("ok1");
  default: $display("no1");
endcase

case (a) inside
//       ^^^^^^
  3'b0??: $display("ok1");
  default: $display("no1");
endcase
```

I would use `case ... inside` rather than `casez`, because `casez` is an inferior, Verilog way of doing it.